# Characters of a quadratic extension and convergence

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, zeta-functions, local-fields, characters

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, $\chi$ a quasi-character of $F^\star$ and $\psi$ a positive character of $E^\star$. I would like to understand why the usual Rankin-Selberg zeta integrals converge, and this question reduces to the convergence of

$$\int_{E^\star} \chi(a) \psi(a) |a|^s d^\times a$$

this convergence seems to be true in a half-plane $Re(s)>s_0$ for some $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, depending only on $\chi$ and $\psi$.

Why is that true? What do we know about characters of $E^\star$ to be able to conclude that straigthforwardly? And why, when converges, this integral gives a polynomial in $q^{—s}$ where $q$ is the cardinality of the residue field?

Comment: I guess from the title that $E / F$ is a quadratic extension? Anyway, something is wrong here ($\chi(a)$ for $a \in E^\times$ is meaningless). You should check carefully what statement it is that you actually want.